# How to compute the recurrence formula without using array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to compute the y_{n+1} = (a * y_n * b) + (b * y_n * a), where a and b are some matrix respectively.

And I coded this recurrence formula using array for yn.

```
yn = []
for n in range(30):
    if n == 0:
        yn.append(a.dot(b) + b.dot(a))
    else:
        yn.append(a.dot(yn[n-1]).dot(b) + b.dot(yn[n-1]).dot(a))
```

However, it turned out this code doesn't work well for large sized matrix because of the memory problem. So, I want a another way to compute this without using array. Can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: Why would you need the array?  Just keep the last two values in two variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one variable.

```
y = a.dot(b) + b.dot(a)
for n in range(1, 30):
    y = a.dot(y).dot(b) + b.dot(y).dot(a)
```